# textField should update as soon as a method is called

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad, uitextfield

I am working on a project which deals with an examination paper. I display only 1 question at a time on the view. After the users answers the question a second question is displayed if the user swipes towards left hand side.

I have placed a textField to display the score at each point in time. I implemented it but my score gets updated only if the user navigates to the next question.
My requirement is that as soon as the question is answered the score should be updated in the textField.

```
scoreField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",currentScore];
```

Is there any technique to do so whenever a question is answered? My paper has 20 questions and has 20 submit buttons so I cannot place the above code at each and every submit button action method. It would be ugly and not effective programming.

Please help if there is any way to solve my case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When and how you are updating currentScore?

Comment: i am updating the score in a method which is called everytime a swipe is done.when a swipe is done all the data related to the question is saved into a dictionary in that method.

Comment: If answering a question changes the score, then you need to set currentScore. You can use a setter as specified in my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be made really simple, and elegant. With a few assumptions:

- There is globally accessible model object that holds the score, for example `+[Examination sharedExammination]`.
- The model object has a KVO (Key-Value-Observing) compatible property like `score`.
- You use a custom subclass of `UILabel` to display the score.

With these assumptions you can let your custom `UILabel` register for KVO changes to to the `score` property and update itself automatically. The implementation of the `UILabel` subclass would include something like this:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [[Examination sharedExamination] addObserver:self
                                          forKeyPath:@"currentScore"
                                             options:0
                                             context:NULL];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)dealloc 
{
    [[Examination sharedExamination] removeObserver:self
                                         forKeyPath:@"currentScore"];
    [super dealloc];
}
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath 
                     ofObject:(id)object 
                       change:(NSDictionary*)change 
                      context:(void*)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"currentScore"]) {
        scoreField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"Score: %d", [object currentScore]];
    } else {
        [super observerValueForKeyPath:keyPath
               ofObject:object
                 change:change
                context:context];
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx PeyloW, i have used textField using xib.and instead [Examination sharedExamination] i placed my textField scoreField in viewDidLoad  [scoreField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"score"  options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL]; i am getting a error as "Request for member 'text' in something not a structure " at self.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score:%d",[object score]]; what might be the problem ? can  u help me with desired changes?

Comment: @efrank In the context of the observation context `object` is the observed object, and `self` is the observer. Change to `scoreField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"score:%@", [object score];`.

Comment: in my case self.scoreField.text is not a valid. so i placed scoreField.text and run the code but my i am meeting my requirement.i have taken scoreField as state in the same class.

Comment: @efrank - Sorry but last comment do not make any sense to me. Please clarify.

Comment: @PeyloW sorry for that. i am getting a error if i place self.scoreField.text=---;removing self solved the error. i mean to say this in my above comment.all these methods are in a single class including my viewDidLoad.my textField name is scoreField and the variable used to update score is currentScore.plz if u dont mind can u reframe the above code using scoreField and currentScore. i think i am failing to addObserver accurately.

Comment: @efrank - The error for not being able to use `self.scoreField` is because you have not defined a property for `scoreField` to wrap your instance variable. Remove reference to `self` or add the property.

Answer (score 2):

If you understand your problem correctly then you don't want to set `scoreField.text` in every submit button handler. I am assuming that you are setting this when navigating to next question. You only need to update this when `currentScore` is changed. So I think it's better to create a setter for `currentScore` and update `scoreField.text` from that. Something like this:

```
- (void)setCurrentScore:(NSInteger)newScore {
    currentScore = newScore;
    scoreField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",currentScore];
}
```

And call `setCurrentScore` whenever you need to change the score. Or even better, you can use a setter property and write your own setter implementation.

Comment: thanks taskinoor for the reply. what i feel is we are not making much difference by creating a setter or even if we do scoreField.text,b'coz the setter method should be called in 20 questions action method.i am trying for a better approach like KeyValue observer where the observer observes the value and makes the changes. i am trying to implement it.any way tnx for your support and continue helping me using kvo.

Comment: @efrank, in that case please update the question so that other members can suggest accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```